# Missing id columns for derived types with TPH strategy after migrating to EFCore 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, ef-core-2.2

I migrated my application from EF6 to EFCore 2.2 and I have a problem with mapping abstract type with derived types into one table. TPH inheritance strategy.

```
public abstract class GoalExpectation : Entity { ... }
public class AtLeastGoalExpectation : GoalExpectation { ... }
public class AtMostGoalExpectation : GoalExpectation { ... }
```

Mapping and db context are defined in such way

```
public class MyDbContext : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
{
    public DbSet<GoalExpectation> GoalExpectations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         // to avoid declare DbSets for derived types (accoring to docs)
         modelBuilder.Entity<AtLeastGoalExpectation>();
         modelBuilder.Entity<AtMostGoalExpectation>();

         modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new GoalExpectationTypeConfig());
    }
}

public class GoalExpectationTypeConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<GoalExpectation>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<GoalExpectation> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("GoalExpectations");

        builder.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator")
            .HasValue<AtLeastGoalExpectation>("AtLeastGoalExpectation")
            .HasValue<AtMostGoalExpectation>("AtMostGoalExpectation")
     }
}
```

I get the following error while executing this query

```
    public List<Goal> GetGoalsWithTimeLimit(long userId, DateTime date)
    {
        var queryable = _dbContext.Goals
            .Include(p => p.ProgressItems)
            .Where(p => p.Owner.Id == userId)
            .Where(p => p.FinishDate.HasValue || p.ProgressFrequency != null);

        return queryable.ToList();
    }
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'AtLeastId'.
>   Invalid column name 'AtMostId'.

Comment: Does not reproduce with the provided code. Needs `mcve`.

Comment: @IvanStoev I updated my post with LINQ query where error occurs

Comment: Jacek, try to look to it from our side - create clean new project and try to reproduce with the code in  the question, and you'll see it's not enough.